# Authentication Failed | GoCart | Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying one of the open source shopping cart built (https://gocartdv.com/) on top of codeigniter.

After the initial installation, it does not authenticate with the default credentials admin/admin to thee admin panel.

Has anyone used gocart and faced this issue?

I am running it on Ubuntu 14.04 and `mod_rewrite` is enables in my apache configs

Comment: Maybe off topic There seems to be lots of issue with It I tried my self don't bother with it any more

Comment: I think I agree. But are there any shopping carts build on top of codeigniter already?

Comment: Not that I know of unless custom built a good and free eCommerce system is opencart very easy to use.